# dynamo python: open revit files from autodesk docs

Tags: python, revit-api

In dynamo / Python, how to open revit file from autodesk docs? Seems like if the revit file is from autodesk docs, it doesn’t really work, keep on freezing. Are there different ways to open the files from the `revit` API?

```
doc = app.OpenDocumentFile(file_path)
```

[python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/637UJ.png)

Comment: can you ctrl+c your python-script while it is frozen? That should give you a stacktrace with some clues. Also, is the file open in another program? That is not a problem for most programs/files, but it can be.

Comment: Also, please copy-paste your code into the question, do not post it as a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are several different [overloads of the OpenDocumentFile method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2024/11420983-6d0d-0022-e24c-2361c4e42fba.htm). None of them cause freezing when used properly. Maybe you are not in a [valid Revit API context](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2020/11/document-session-id-api-context-and-external-events.html#3)? Btw, the best place to discuss Dynamo questions right now is probably the [DynamoBIM forum](https://forum.dynamobim.com).

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks so much for getting back to me. I have figured out the solution from DynamoBIM forum (https://forum.dynamobim.com/t/dynamo-python-open-revit-files-from-autodesk-docs/97501/4). Seems like it was due to opening cloudr revit models.

Comment: Congratulations on solving the issue and thank you for your appreciation. Please up-vote my answer, then. Thank you!